# Is there a way to make NAnt catch exceptions and run a roll back script?

Tags: sql, error-handling, nant, osql

I am using NAnt to run some scrips for a deployment. It has simplified the process a lot. The issue now is that when there is an error I want the NAnt task to run my roll back scripts. However I only know of the option to fail on error for my tasks. Is there any sort of baked in way to set properties on error or to use the the chose statement to redirect the flow of the tasks if a previous task fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer looking for another question about NAnt ([error handling in nant build scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/868790/46810)). This will fill the need I have to automatically kick off roll back scripts. Only thing catch is that is not a part of base NAnt but [NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/), but that a minor detail.